# Scala - Quicklens Enumeration

Tags: scala, quicklens

I'd like replace all enum field `value1` to `value2`, using Quicklens the compiler says

```
scalac: Error while emitting
lazy value MyEnum$module
```

the code:

```scala
object MyEnum extends Enumeration {
  type MyEnum = Value
  val value1, value2 = Value
}

import com.softwaremill.quicklens._
import MyEnum._

case class Foo(name: List[MyEnum])
case class Bar(address: Foo, age: Int)

val bar = Bar(Foo(List(value1)), 35)

val b: Bar = bar.modify(_.address.name.eachWhere(_ == value1)).setTo(value2)
```

Comment: Couldn't reproduce, what environment did you use?
https://scastie.scala-lang.org/NN6qhF25R2G1l0cB3lOMaQ

Comment: adding `addSbtPlugin("org.lyranthe.sbt" % "partial-unification" % "1.1.2")` it works. Thanks